# Black's formula derivation: expectation of a indicator times a random variable

Tags: put, indicator, expected-value

[image]

In this derivation of Black's formula for puts, we have that $\mathbb{E}[e^X   1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}]$ somehow equals $S_0  e^{\mu + 0.5 \sigma^2} N$ (as above in the formula).

I tried breaking apart the formula into

$$\mathbb{E}[e^X   1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}]) = \mathbb{E}(e^X)\mathbb{E}(1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}) + \operatorname{Cov}(e^X,1_{e^X \leq K/S_0})$$

and ended up with

$$S_0  e^{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2}  N((\ln(K/S_0) - \mu)/\sigma) + \operatorname{Cov}(e^X, 1_{e^X \leq K/S_0})$$

by applying the MGF and standardizing the inside of the Normal

and now I'm stuck on what to do next to simplify it into the form given in step 3.

My question is how to calculate away the Covariance term to make it match last line of the circled formula.